# Using REST API to get Site Groups in SP 2013

Tags: 2013, javascript, client-object-model, rest

I'm trying to use the REST API in SharePoint 2013 to get the site groups.

I've been using this link for a little help...
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj245927.aspx

It's to do it with the Client Object Model and the REST API, I have tried both.
The problem is that when I call to get Site Groups, with any of the below example urls (or using the JSOM) I seem to get every group in the whole site collection. Not just those specific to the site (SPWeb).

```
// I expect to get the groups in the root SPWeb

    http://{sitecollection}/_api/Web/SiteGroups
```

I expect to get the groups in the SPWeb at `<subsite>/<subsite2>`, but I get the same result as the above call.

```
http://{sitecollection}/{subsite}/{subsite2}/_api/Web/SiteGroups
```

The extra groups I am seeing are actually in subsite2, but even when I change to subsite/subsite3, I still get the same result?

It's like they are cached calls or something...is there something I am missing??
Is this call related to the calling user at all?

The server side object model does not have this problem and works as expected.

Comment: Funny how the reason pops up once you write it down!  SiteGroups is not the same as Groups.  However I cant seem to get Groups on the JSOM.  Any ideas?

Comment: Yes. SiteGroups will give you all the groups from the Site Collection. http://msdn.microsoft.com/EN-US/library/jj246603.aspx

Comment: But is there a way (in the REST api or JSOM) to get the groups associated with a specific SPWeb?  I can only think of doing something with Associations and Binding in some crazy loops!!?

Comment: hi @Eric , can you please tell how can i pass a  group name which starts with or  contains keyword in the method getgroups?in C#, SSOM, its available , but in JSOM/ REST is it possible to achieve ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Even though [Web class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.client.web(v=office.15).aspx) does not expose `Groups` property like [SPWeb class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.spweb.aspx) does, you could still retrieve a collection that contains all the groups for the website.

### How to retrieve groups for a web

Use [RoleAssignmentCollection.Groups property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.client.roleassignmentcollection.groups(v=office.15).aspx) to get the groups that directly belong to the access control list (ACL). for this securable object.

CSOM

```
using (var ctx = new ClientContext(url))
{ 
    var web = ctx.Web;
    var webGroups = web.RoleAssignments.Groups;
}
```

REST

```
/_api/web/roleassignments/groups
```

Comment: Nice that you can use this on any securable object!

Comment: how to export these spgroups into a  csv file or excel ?

Answer (score 3):

With REST you can filter based on the Title of the groups. However this depends on group names containing the site name. Naming should also be consistent e.g. starting all group names with site name. The url for such a request would be

```
http://{sitecollection}/_api/web/sitegroups?$filter=startswith(Title,'site name') eq true
```

For more information about filtering take a look at http://www.odata.org/documentation/odata-v2-documentation/uri-conventions/#45_Filter_System_Query_Option_filter

Comment: Thanks.  That doesn't really give me the groups associated with a site, just a filter on group names.  Like you said, it depends 100% on the site name in the group name, which rather pigeon holes that group.

Comment: dead link on there